# Is there a Python API for R's ggplot2?

Tags: python, api, ggplot2, python-ggplot

My question is as simple as the title: i want to use `R`'s `ggplot2` but all my data handling is done in `Python`: is there a Python API for `ggplot2`, or an easy way to use `ggplot2` through `Python` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) allows you to call R from Python and provides with data conversion utilities. You can use ggplot2 function with the [Graphics package](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/graphics.html), look at this section for some [examples](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/graphics.html#package-ggplot2).

Answer (score 5):

Check this out: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot

This is a python port of R's ggplot2.

Answer (score 2):

Great answers so far, but don't forget about Bokeh: https://bokeh.org/

All sorts of great ways to visualize data, emulating ggplot2 in some ways, but also inspired by the amazing D3.js library.

Ever wanted to make something like this in Python?

[image: viz]

Here's the quickstart guide: http://docs.bokeh.org/docs/quickstart.html#quickstart

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) to call R from within python or there is [ggplot for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot) if you do not like [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).