# Are all functionalities of ggplot2 available in Python?

Tags: python, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

the title is actually my question. I googled quite a bit, checked Quora and searched through Stackoverflow. Since I couldn't find an answer to my question I think the question is warranted.

So basically my question is twofold:

1) are all the ggplot2 functionalities available in python (especially jupyter notebook)?

2) If yes, can the R tutorials applied directly?

Kind regards
Fabian

Comment: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/?

Comment: yes. just use rpy2.

Comment: I have visited said webpage, to me it looks like it is regarding ggplot and not ggplot2, also the documentation and description is virtually nonexistant, which is why I asked here. (see for example: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/facet_grid.html) -> unjustified downvote if you ask me.
Also the fact that Gene Burnisky answered the question with no proves that the question was valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, the answer is no. In Jupyter Notebook, however, you can interface with R. In brief, do your calculations in Python and then plot using R in the same notebook. For details, check out this [notebook](https://github.com/cliburn/sta-663-2016/blob/master/lectures/18B_Foreing_Language_Interface.ipynb).

However, if you are going to use python, you might as well learn matplotlib - the canonical python library for graphing. In my opinion, it's a bit more flexible and it is quite similar to Matplot's plotting functionalities.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gene. I actually am somewhat familiar with matplotlib, but started doing udacities course on machine learning and they are using ggplot. So I got curious. I also like the syntax and seem not to be able to wrap my head around matplotlib, speaking of which, do you know of a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned in some of the comments, you can also try the ggplot2-inspired [`ggplot`](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/) library. It is not as mature as `matplotlib` or `seaborn`. Alternatively, you can try `rpy2` (see this related question: [Is there a Python API for R's ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887757/is-there-a-python-api-for-rs-ggplot2)).
2. `ggplot` is not a port of R's `ggplot2`, so there's no guarantee that the R tutorials will just work--though some probably will or will at least get you on the right track. As the [README](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot) says:

   > It is not intended to be a feature-for-feature port of ggplot2 for R--though there is much greatness in ggplot2, the Python world could stand to benefit from it. So there **will be feature overlap**, but not neccessarily mimicry (after all, R is a little weird).